# How to add screenshots from iOS Store links in the iPhone Notes app?

Tags: iphone, ios, automation, notes.app

This is a strange one. Last year I created a Notes folder with my iPhone and started saving links to some apps from the iOS Store, each one as a separate note. I just added a title and pasted the link, and it seems the Notes app added each link as a neat app screenshot + icon. This is how it looks like in the Notes app, notice how they have a thumbnail preview:

[image]

And this is how the notes look like when I open:

[image]

Somehow I can't do that anymore, whenever i create a new note and paste a link to the store it just saves the URL as a regular web link.

I can't find information about this anywhere on the web, was that a function that got removed in the latest iOS updates? Or is there a secret magic way to make links to the iOS Store appear as screenshots in my notes?